# Default document over HTTPS not working from iPhone 6 and iPad?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, safari

Server Configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro
- ColdFusion 2016 Standard
- IIS 10

I have a Web application that uses the built-in default documents module throughout the application to obfuscate file names. When I try to access any of the Website's URLs over HTTPS that refer to folders (e.g. 1) `https://example.com/`, 2) `https://example.com/folder/`, etc.) that map to a Default Document (index.cfm, index.htm) from Safari or Chrome on an iPhone 6 or older iPad (devices readily available for me to test from) the connection seems to hang for a while and then eventually fails with a generic browser message (I don't have it in front of me but I don't think it's needed, please read on).

I can reach all URLs from any PC, desktop or laptop from Chrome, Firebug, IE, and Edge, and from a colleague's newer Mac laptop. I tried testing with generic "hello world" htm and cfm files to rule-out browser engine interpretations of code: html/jquery/etc..

To rule out the iPhone 6 being the problem I created the exact same set of test files from another server on a completely different domain and the default documents server-up successfully.

I can reach URLs over HTTPS from the iPhone 6 or iPad when they include the file name (e.g. all the way to: `/index.htm`, or: `/folder/index.cfm`).

I can reach all URLs over HTTP (not secure) from the iPhone 6 or iPad so long as the request is over an insecure channel (e.g. URLs 1 and 2 further above but with HTTP instead of HTTPS).

On the server side I setup a broad Failed Request Tracing rule (all HTTP Responses 100-999). When I watch the directory during a failed request attempt I see XML files being created for several seconds from a single request (implying that the iPhone browser is repeatedly trying to connect?). The sequence in the XML trace logs seems to indicate all is well (correct handler mappings appear to trigger/fire, HTTP 200 OK response) for a while until this:

> Informational
>   166.  -GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END
>
> An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection.

It made no difference when I tried every combination of the following in IIS 10:

- Move the StaticFile Handler Mapping above the ExtensionlessUrlHandler* Handler Mappings.
- Set Anonymous Authentication to either Specific User: IUSR or Application Pool Identity.
- Grant read and execute permissions to the Web root folder.
- Set the Application Pool, Managed Pipeline setting of the Website to either: Classic or Integrated.

Where is my problem? It does not appear to be the IIS 10 settings nor the iPhone. The SSL certificate seems to be working when the above test cases succeed.

Comment: We have run into this as well. No solution yet...
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640456/iis-10-coldfusion-11-served-website-wont-load-default-home-page-on-ios-mobile-d/43658960#43658960)